# Arquivo não está sendo salvo na pasta especificada com php

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um upload de uma imagem ajax e php, o nome gerado no php é gravado normal no banco de dados porém, o arquivo em si não é gravado/movido para a pasta "upload" dentro do meu projeto. Não apresenta qualquer tipo de mensagem de erro.

Se eu der um `var_dump($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);` por exemplo ele imprime

```
string(14) "/tmp/phpYoKhfM" string(43) "upload/47ebbe8e65ea9963b7480838fb34f1d6.jpg"
```

Ao verificar a pasta que localiza na raiz do projeto não existe nada dentro. Preciso de alguma orientação sobre isso.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario">
   <input name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" id="cpf" readonly>
   <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Nova senha">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
   <input type="hidden" name="id">

   <input type="submit" value="Atualizar" id="nova-senha">
</form>
```

Arquivo que insere os campos no banco de dados e move a imagem para a pasta upload

```
try{
  //Pega a extensão do arquivo
  $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -4));

  //Gera o nome do arquivo
  $novo_nome= md5(time()) . $extensao;
  $diretorio = "upload/";

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

  //Instancia o método para enviar o alguns valores
  $trocarSenha = new EsqueciSenha();
  $teste = $trocarSenha->alterarSenha($_POST['senha'], $_POST['id'], $novo_nome);
  echo json_encode($teste);
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "Erro";
}
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o caminho absoluto? `$diretorio = __DIR__ . "/upload/";`

Comment: Tentei aqui e mesmo assim a pasta permanece vazia, eu tentei até por via de duvida criar várias pastas em varios lugares, mas sem sucesso. Não sei se vai fazer diferença mas utilizo o debian linux. Precisa de alguma permissão na pasta upload? @gmsantos

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` retorna false? Habilita os warnings para ter uma ideia melhor do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Você disse uma coisa importante os warnings, estava tendo problemas de permissão.

Comment: Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema em sistema linux, sendo que migrei recentemente, resolvi com ' chmod -R 777 sua_pasta ', usei -R porque não sabia onde cairia o arquivo então dei permissão pra as subpastas.